# How can I SUM values that don't have a common GROUP BY condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like so:

[image]

What I am trying to do is get the sum of each Iteration, so my result set will end up like so:

[image]

Notice that ItemNum 2, 8, 10, and 11 don't exist for Iteration 1, however they should still be accounted for. The table only stores updates made on each Iteration, so since Item 2, 8, 10, and 11 weren't updated, they don't have an Iteration 1 record. This is where I am stumped.

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT Iteration, SUM(Value)
FROM TableA
GROUP BY Iteration
```

This obviously just sums up each Iteration, but Item 2, 8, 10, and 11 aren't getting summed into Iteration 1. Can someone help point me in the right direction? I have looked into `CROSS APPLY` but I am not sure if this is the route to take.

Comment: Try this. SELECT Iteration,  SUM(Value)
FROM TableA
GROUP BY Iteration    Let me know whether working or not.

Comment: Can the missing values come from different iterations?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes they can

Comment: @GaurangDave that's what I have tried already. Doing that doesn't account for the missing values from Iteration 1

Comment: Can you explain how did you get 12.5 for iteration 1?

Comment: @uzi it's the sum of all of the items from Iteration 1 plus the missing items from Iteration 0 (2, 8, 10, and 11). So 2.2 + 3.3 + 0 + 0.9 + 0.7 + 4.9 + 0.6 + 0 + 0 + 0.4 + 0.7

Comment: 2.2 + 3.3 + 0 + 0.9 + 0.7 + 4.9 + 0.6 + 0 + 0 + 0.4 + 0.7 = 13.7 not 12.5

Comment: @uzi woops, apologies. I uploaded the wrong screenshot. I'll updated it so it'll makes more sense.

Comment: @uzi 2 + 3.3 + 2.7 + 0.7 + 0.5 + 1.6 + 0.5 + 0 + 0.1 + 0.4 + 0.7 = 12.5

Comment: @OhlPatrol another option for you is recursive cte. For that you should know exact number of `Itemnum's`. Are they fixed? But I do not think that it will be faster than @Gordon Linoff solution

Answer (score 1):

You can get the missing values, but it is tricky:

```
select it.iteration, sum(t.value)
from (select distinct iteration from t) it cross join
     (select distinct itemnum from t) i outer apply
     (select top (1) t.value
      from t
      where t.iteration <= it.iteration and t.itemnum = i.itemnum
      order by t.iteration desc
     ) t  
group by it.iteration;
```